# Installing Windows 8.1 on SSD and Ubuntu on a partition of a secondary HDD?

Tags: dual-boot

Currently I have 2 drives in my system, a main SSD where my Windows 8.1 copy is installed, and a 2TB storage drive for all files.

My plan is to partition the 2TB hard drive into a 200gb partition solely for Ubuntu. I'm not keen on being asked whether I want to boot into Windows or Ubuntu everytime, so I'm hoping that by making a partition on my HDD and installing Ubuntu on that, I won't be asked every time. If I'm correct, to boot to Windows I just need to boot up from SSD, and to boot to Ubuntu, I just need to boot from my HDD. Is this correct?

If so, how would I go about doing this? Do I just install Ubuntu normally from a CD? Would I need any tweaks?

Any advice is appreciated as I am a novice on this. I would like my Ubuntu installation to be seperate from my Windows, in that I can just delete the partition if I no longer need Linux.

Thanks.

Comment: Is Windows UEFI boot? And is 2TB drive gpt partitioned? Post this from terminal in live installer: `sudo parted -l` Generally better to have both systems in same boot mode, either both UEFI or both BIOS. If not you cannot use grub menu to dual boot, but have to use UEFI boot menu and may have to turn on/off UEFI or BIOS/CSM/Legacy.

Comment: Windows is a UEFI boot - the 2tb hard drive is not partitioned as of yet, but I plan to partition it using the live cd into a 200gb ext4 format. How do I ensure that I'm installing ubuntu in UEFI mode?

Comment: How you boot installer is how it installs: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI and: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported  If installing to sdb, best to have an ESP - efi system partition on sdb, but grub will only install to ESP on sda. If you disconnect Windows drive then it will install only to your data drive. If you partition in advance be sure to use gpt & enclude the ESP as first partition.

Comment: This confused me on so many levels haha. I'll give those 2 links a read, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

A similar question about windows and ubuntu from another user is [Windows 10 & Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/666085/windows-10-ubuntu) read my advice and try reading both articles I linked there.

You can alternatively install Ubuntu as a virtual box and try before switching to Ubuntu when you are comfortable.