# Windows 10 & Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, windows-10

I want to download ubuntu for my win10 as a secondary OS for... reasons. Too long story.

I downloaded ubuntu 14.04 from disk I found from library. I had to use disk instead of internet download because poor connection. (it would take few days to download all)

First of all i had to use tools disk offered because computer did not open ubuntu in next restart.

Now each time my whole computer starts, it says something like Windows could not be started and do you want to see OS selection screen.

Beginning in windows selection begins windows normally, as I now write this post in it.

But start with ubuntu makes another ' Windows could not be started' screen. Strange. I can just begin with windows.

How can I launch pc with ubuntu in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I would advise backing up your windows 10 files, creating rescue disk for windows 10 and noting down windows 10 keys(i.e windows 8.1/7 keys in case you just upgraded) Read about UEFI in this article: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI and further read [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

Answer (score -1):

@Jabutosama sounds like what may work for you would be to install Ubuntu as your main OS and then install KVM (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation) that would allow you to run Windows 10 as a virtual machine. I've included a link to the Ubuntu Help page for how to install KVM. Hope that helps, good luck.

Comment: how it affects my windows 10 files i currently have? I have lot of things that i don't want to be lost.

Comment: This won't solve their problem, @Techieman75, 'cause this would remove Win10 and the corresponding files/programs/etc.

Comment: You would loose all your files unless you backed them up and restored them. Sounds like what you want to do is run Ubuntu inside of Windows 10. Technically this is NOT the place to post such a question as it is really a Windows 10 question. I would recommend enabling Hyper-V (http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2087-hyper-v-virtualization-setup-use-windows-10-a.html) and then installing Ubuntu in a virtual machine. Should do the trick for you as long as you have hardware that supports virtulization.